Unable to deploy Endpoint Elevation Management in Intune
I tried to deploy the Elevation Settings in MS Intune. Specifically in Endpoint Security, Endpoint Privilege Management. I tried different settings, I checked the licenses and that user is licensed.
I am not sure what else to do but when it gets deployed, I get the following useless error:
Checkin status: Error
When I double click the link I get the following error:
Send elevation data for reporting
Noncompliant
What does it mean it is Noncompliant? Where? How do I check what is not compliant?
All the other policies, software has been installed without any problem.
Can someone suggest what to do, what to look?
Thanks
